# JSON working on localhost but not server?

Tags: php, json

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_object($u_result)) {
  //print_r($res);
  $task_id = $res - > task_id;
  //print_r($json['task_info']);
  //$task_id = $json['task_info'][0]->task_id;
  $sql_g = "SELECT `grade` FROM `t_grades` WHERE `student_id`='$student_id' AND `task_id`= $task_id";
  $res_g = mysql_query($sql_g);

  if(mysql_num_rows($res_g) > 0) {
    $row_g = mysql_fetch_object($res_g);
    $res->grade = $row_g['grade'];
  }
  else {
    $res->grade = 'none';
  }
  //print_r($res);
  $json['task_info'][] = $res;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array like this.
```

This works fine in localhost but returns an error on the server. What would cause this?

Comment: what's the pvp version of your localhost vs server?

Comment: `$res->grade = $row_g['grade'];` should be `$res->grade = $row_g->grade;`

Comment: I have added it as an answer, you might like to accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what the problem is. You're using `mysql_fetch_object()` (which is deprecated, by the way, as is the whole [`mysql_*` family](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)), and then trying to access it as an array. Change your code as follows:

```
$row_g = mysql_fetch_object($res_g);
$res->grade = $row_g->grade;
```